# How to loop through 2 dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, coldfusion, cfloop

I have two dimensional array that looks like this after I used  to output this on the screen:

```
array
1   
array
1   0600
2   
array
1   0
3   
array
1   0600
4   
array
1   0
5   
array
1   0615
6   
array
1   0
7   
array
1   0615
8   
array
1   0
9   
array
1   0630
10  
array
1   0
11  
array
1   0630
12  
array
1   1
```

So I want to loop through my array and output values in this order:

```
0600   0
0600   0
0615   0
0615   0
0630   0  
0630   1
```

Here is the code how I created my Array:

```
<cfloop list="#ListGetAt(dataList,i,",")#" index="z" delimiters="|">
    <cfoutput query="getR" group="theYear">
        <cfset name = myArray.append([z])>
        <cfif Description eq z>
            <cfset count = myArray.append([theCount])>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset count = myArray.append([0])>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

So how I can loop now to get this two records in order as I showed you above? I tried this but that did not work:

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(myArray)#" index="i">
        <cfloop array="#myArray#" index="j">
            #i# - #myArray[1][j]#<br/>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

**Edit:**  When I used this code:

```
<cfloop array="#myArray#" index="i"> 
    <cfloop array="#myArray#" index="j"> 
        <cfoutput> #myArray[i][j]#<br/> </cfoutput> 
    </cfloop> 
</cfloop>
```

I got this error:

> ```
> The value coldfusion.runtime.Array cannot be converted to a number.
> ```

If anyone can help with this problem please let me know.

Comment: I'm not a coldfusion guy but shouldn't you be indexing with [i][j] e.g. #myArray[i][j] not 1 and j

Comment: Side note, the phrase *did not work:* does not tell us much. While I suspect user5976242 is correct, try and include a description of the actual result, and specifically how it differs from what you expected.

Comment: When I used this code: <cfloop array="#myArray#" index="i">
   <cfloop array="#myArray#" index="j">
    <cfoutput>
     #myArray[i][j]#<br/>
    </cfoutput>
   </cfloop>
  </cfloop> I got this error: The value coldfusion.runtime.Array cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: @user3023588 - Okay, it makes a lot more sense now that you posted the error message ;-) If you think about the error message says exactly what the problem is... you are using an *array* loop - which means the `index` will contain the value of one of the elements in the array.  However, the output code is designed for use with a from/to loop, where the `index` value is a position or number, ie 1,2,3,etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you'd get the output from your 2-dimensional array.

```
<cfscript>
data = [
    ["0600", 0],
    ["0600", 0],
    ["0615", 0],
    ["0615", 0],
    ["0630", 0],
    ["0630", 1]
];

// script version
for (foo in data) {
    writeOutput(foo[1] & " " & foo[2] & "<br>");
}

</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
tag version...<br>
<cfloop array="#data#" index="foo">
    #foo[1]# #foo[2]#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

An example of it in use here: http://trycf.com/gist/86b42b56ef7348ec0d44/acf2016?theme=monokai

However, I'm not sure why you're using a 2-dimensional array when an array of structs (key value pairs) seems an easier way to do it:

For example:

```
<cfscript>
data = [
    {key:"0600", count:0},
    {key:"0600", count:0},
    {key:"0615", count:0},
    {key:"0615", count:0},
    {key:"0630", count:0},
    {key:"0630", count:1}
];

// script version
for (foo in data) {
    writeoutput(foo.key & " " & foo.count & "<br>");
}

</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
tag version...<br>
<cfloop array="#data#" index="foo">
    #foo.key# #foo.count#<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: How I can create array struct with key and count values from this code: <cfloop list="#ListGetAt(dataList,i,",")#" index="z" delimiters="|">
    <cfoutput query="getR" group="theYear">
        <cfset name = myArray.append([z])>
        <cfif Description eq z>
            <cfset count = myArray.append([theCount])>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset count = myArray.append([0])>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop> ?

Comment: Something like `<cfset myArray.append({name: z, count: theCount})>`

Comment: I stumbled upon this looking for something else but might I saw this is a brilliant answer that can quite easily be added upon. and +1 for providing script syntax, too.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix your loop by:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop array="#myArray#" index="firstDimension"> 
    <cfloop array="#firstDimension#" index="secondDimension"> 
        #secondDimension#<br/>
    </cfloop> 
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```